# windows change directory using perl

Tags: windows, perl

I need a sample code to change directory in windows using a perl script

Current Folder `C:\Users\emp1>`

after executing the perl code the windows command prompt should point to `C:\Users\emp1\newfolder>`

`chdir` is not working ,kindly need expert help

Comment: you cannot change the environment of a parent process.

Comment: You can do that with Bash and an alias command that  sources a bash script that changes current directory using cd. See for example : [Creating an alias to Change Directory and have that directory be the current working directory in new terminal tabs](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156036/creating-an-alias-to-change-directory-and-have-that-directory-be-the-current-wor)

Comment: Well open a subshell to that directory...

Comment: Thanks for the responses,my rest of the tasks are written in PERL, so need a perl option

Comment: `chdir` is (probably) working just fine. It's changing the current directory *of the process running the Perl script*.